# using "Sqlldr "in Java getting an Exception Cannot run program "sqlldr": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, oracle

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlldr": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)   do I need to do any path settings for java and oracle for using sqlloader

Stand alone Java Code:

```
public class SqlLoader{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  String sqlldrCmd = "sqlldr " + userName + "/" + password + "@"
            + dbname + "  CONTROL=" + ctlFile + " LOG=" + logFile;
    
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(sqlldrCmd);
}
}
```

Ctl file:

load data
infile 'input.csv'
APPEND into table  Tablename
fields terminated by ","
trailing NULLCOLS
(
ID,
Name,
ACTIVE_DATE,
EXPIRE_DATE,
)

example.csv
ID,Name
1,abc

Comment: Do you have the SQLLDR installed at all?

Comment: No, SQLLDR is not installed, but Oracle Client is installed. Could you please tell how to install SQLLDR

Comment: SQL*Loader comes as part of any Oracle database server software. Or, it is part of Oracle client. Depending on what you chose to install, you have - or don't have - SQLLDR. Note that Instant Client doesn't contain SQLLDR. So, maybe you do have it; did you search for it? If not, well, you'll have to install it. Downloadable from the Oracle Technology Network site.

Comment: [Instant client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html) has SQL\*Loader available in its 'tools' package, which you can install on top of the 'basic' package. You will need to tell Java where to find it though.

Comment: Oracle Instant Client 12.2 is installed but there is no tools package available in it

Comment: Then you need to download it; old versions are available from the link in my previous comment - from there click 'Download Now', pick your operating system, and scroll down to version 12.2.0.1. (Depending on where the file is, or could be, you could also consider using an external table instead of SQL\*Loader.)

Comment: The log file should give you some pointers.

Comment: Actually Oracle Instant Client 12.1 version is installed for that no tools package is provided

Comment: Log file also not created